# Why did Google mark my app as harmful or dangerous

Tags: android, apk

Google has a function to detect harmful or dangerous apps: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/2812853?hl=en

My app ([GameGuardian](https://gameguardian.net/forum/files/file/2-gameguardian/)) is being treated as [harmful or dangerous](https://gameguardian.net/forum/topic/7403-known-problems/#comment-42178). Why?

It started happening after version 7.2.0 - no significant changes have been made in this version though.

Is there any way to appeal the decision of Google? Or get an explanation why this is so, and how to fix it?

The current list of permissions are as follows:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>    
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REAL_GET_TASKS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_DETAILED_TASKS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.UPDATE_APP_OPS_STATS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE" tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"/>
```

For version 7.2.0, which was when the detection first occurred, the list is as follows:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>    
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

So the permissions are the same between the two versions, in which 7.1.0 is not detected as dangerous.

EDIT:

I find app with same problem: [SELinuxModeChanger](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2524485)

I think both detection caused working with SELinux and YAMA. I go try hide this usage.

Comment: I would imagine it has something to do with <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER"/>. The only question I would have is why verision 7.1.0 wasn't marked as dangerous.

Comment: bro. Your app have caused me a lot of troubles. My question[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40992853/how-to-prevent-time-cheating-on-offline-game-based-on-cocos2dx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I found out, Google looks for certain patterns in the application file and its behavior.

In this case, the problem was caused by using the command `setenforce 0` and although the application and then reverts to the old security (by calling `setenforce 1`, if it was set previously), for Google it was enough.

After the calls were made conditional and the line is masked in the code - the application is no longer marked as dangerous.

Given all the above, we can also conclude that the analysis is fully automatic, as I suggested earlier. Whether it is handmade, it would not help.

The only question remains a mystery why the version 7.2.0 was also labeled as the conduct that behavior was only added in version 7.2.1.

Maybe it was just because the application has the same package name and signature. Although it is strange, considering that the next version, after correction, are no longer marked, though the name and signature of the package are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Although your app is apparently harmless, the following could be the reasons for it being marked harmful.

- Needs Superuser Permissions
- Modifies or tampers with other existing apps(Since it adds money and stuff to other games)
- Requires Internet Access along with a host of other permissions(They might suspect you could be secretly phoning home to your website)
- Since your app tampers with other apps and changes those gems or premium currency, this could hurt Google's business interests.

All in all your app will raise is a red flag to any sane person who doesn't have the time to evaluate your app to the maximum.  I hope you find my answer useful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do not think that Google manually check applications. Most likely it's automatic algorithms.

In this case, the query root, can not be considered sufficient cause. Firstly, the resolution specified here is not universally accepted. Secondly, there are a lot of applications in Google Play, receiving root and not labeled as dangerous.

As for the rest, it's only possible for manual verification, which is unlikely. Besides observation about third-party servers..

Comment: Anyway, pls accept the answer and / or upvote it if you like it.

Comment: I do it if will find info from answer helpful.

Comment: @Enyby: "I do not think that Google manually check applications" -- AFAIK, they have been for the past few months.